# C++/WinRT: MIDL 3.0 type: Char - compile of generated code returns 'T must be WinRT type'. Is there a support usage?

Tags: c++-winrt

Using the idl source containing the MIDL 3.0 simple type Char:

```
namespace BrokenMIDL_Char
{
    [default_interface]
    runtimeclass MainPage : Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.Page
    {
        MainPage();
        Int32 MyProperty;
        Char MyStationLetter_1;
        //Char MyStationLetter_2;
        //Char MyStationLetter_3;
    }
}
```

And the supporting functions

```
    wchar_t MyStationLetter_1()
    {
        throw hresult_not_implemented();
    }

    void MyStationLetter_1(wchar_t /*value*/)
    {
        throw hresult_not_implemented();
    }

     char16_t MyStationLetter_2()
    {
        throw hresult_not_implemented();
    }

    void MyStationLetter_2(char16_t /*value*/)
    {
        throw hresult_not_implemented();
    }


    char MyStationLetter_3()
    {
        throw hresult_not_implemented();
    }

    void MyStationLetter_3(char /*value*/)
    {
        throw hresult_not_implemented();
    }
```

Results in an error

> T must be a WinRT type

My understanding was that the MIDL 3.0 types are the definition the WinRT types.

The MIDL compiler emits:

```
//------------------------------------------------------------------------------
// <auto-generated>
//     This code was generated by a tool.
//
//     Changes to this file may cause incorrect behavior and will be lost if
//     the code is regenerated.
// </auto-generated>
//------------------------------------------------------------------------------
template<typename TDeclaringType, typename TValue>
void SetValueTypeMember_MyStationLetter_1(
    ::winrt::Windows::Foundation::IInspectable const& instance,
    ::winrt::Windows::Foundation::IInspectable const& value)
{
    instance.as<TDeclaringType>().MyStationLetter_1(::winrt::unbox_value<TValue>(value));
}
```

Comment: What is `T` in this case? There is no `T` in the code shown.

Comment: T is part of the (defined by) the MIDL compiler generated file code.

Comment: Can you show THAT code?

Comment: The MIDL compiler emits
```
template<typename TDeclaringType, typename TValue>
void SetValueTypeMember_MyStationLetter_1(
    ::winrt::Windows::Foundation::IInspectable const& instance, 
    ::winrt::Windows::Foundation::IInspectable const& value)
{
    instance.as<TDeclaringType>().MyStationLetter_1(::winrt::unbox_value<TValue>(value));
}
```

Comment: That should have been edited into your question, not posted in comments.  I have done so for you this time, next time please be sure to post ALL relevant details.  That being said, I still don't see any `T` in this code, so which `T` is it complaining about exactly? Assuming `TDeclaringType` or `TValue`, what are they actually being set to in the instantiation of the template?

Comment: So ... have you actually ever used the c++/winrt idl compiler?

Comment: No, and I'm sure many other C++ devs here haven't used it, either.  Doesn't mean we can't still help you.  C++/WinRT is just a wrapper library that works in any standard-compliant C++17 compiler.

Comment: Ok, but the question is about the MIDL compiler and the supported data types.

Comment: In a default C++/WinRT project, midl.exe doesn't generate code. It produces a .winmd file that's processed by cppwinrt.exe which in turn generates the code. If I'm not mistaken, cppwinrt.exe writes its version to the generated files. This seems to not be the case here. Are you using an old/outdated version by any chance? In fact, what version are you using?

Comment: NuGet v2.0.201102.2 (Latest)

Comment: Just double-checked, and I only found the `<auto-generated>` tags in the XAML binding code. That code is generated and to be used unmodified. You aren't meant to provide your custom implementations there. The customization points are in the files generated under *Generated Files\sources*. Those are the skeleton implementations of your implementation types. It's not clear to me where the second code snippet in the question came from.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

During testing, I have a solution you could make a try.

You could open the **Property** tab > **Properties** > **Configuration Properties** > **C/C++** > **Language**, find **Treat Wchar_t As Built in Type** property and select the **No(/Zc:wchar_t-)** option. Then, try to build your project.

Comment: Yes, this works.  I might mention that this is not the default setting used in the project templates installed by CppWinRT vsix.